# Binary redirection in Turtle

Tags: haskell, haskell-turtle

I would like to do something similar to:

`curl -s http://example.com/some/file.bin >/usr/local/bin/foo`

Since `Shell` is polymorphic, I can probably do this with Turtle as-is, but all the examples operate on lines of `Shell Text` and I haven't internalized enough Haskell to navigate it. Is there an idiomatic way to get `Shell Bytestring` or another solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of version 1.3.0, Turtle now has a Turtle.Bytes module just for this:

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/turtle/docs/Turtle-Bytes.html

Answer (score 3):

The answer is, not yet, but there is an issue open for this here:

https://github.com/Gabriel439/Haskell-Turtle-Library/issues/68

I proposed an example API for this in that issue and you might want to chime in on that issue to see if that API would be okay for your use case.